# Move object using Raycast hitpoint with offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am trying to create a simple `ObjectMover` class to move objects within a base (think Clash of Clans base editing).

The issue I am having is that when an object is selected using a `RayCast` it jumps to the RayCast `hit.point` as the `collider` for the object can be hit on the edge and will then move to be centered on the `hit.point`.

I have tried using an offset and am sure it is something trivial but having a brain fart and not able to find the solution.

**ObjectMover.cs**

```c#
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    public class ObjectMover : MonoBehaviour
    {
#pragma warning disable 0649
        [SerializeField] private GameObject _tmpObjectToMove;
        [SerializeField] private LayerMask _groundLayerMask;
        [SerializeField] private LayerMask _objectsLayerMask;
#pragma warning restore 0649
    
        private Camera _cam;
        private GameObject _movableObject;
        private bool _objectIsSelected;
        private Vector3 _objectSelectionOffset;
    
        private void Awake()
        {
            _cam = Camera.main;
        }
    
        private void Start()
        {
            //TMP call and object instantiation for testing purposes
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(_tmpObjectToMove, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
            MakeObjectMoveable(obj);
        }
    
        private IEnumerator UpdatePosition()
        {
            while (_movableObject != null)
            {
                if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
                {
                    TestObjectSelection();
                }
                else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
                {
                    if (_objectIsSelected)
                    {
                        _objectIsSelected = false;
                    }
                }
    
                if (_objectIsSelected)
                {
                    _movableObject.transform.position = GetNewPosition();
                }
    
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    
        public void MakeObjectMoveable(GameObject objectToMakeMovable)
        {
            _movableObject = objectToMakeMovable;
            StartCoroutine(UpdatePosition());
        }
    
        private Vector3 GetNewPosition()
        {
            if (_movableObject != null)
            {
                Ray ray = _cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 200f, _groundLayerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
                {
                    Vector3 pos = hitInfo.point - _objectSelectionOffset;
                    return new Vector3(pos.x, 0f, pos.z);
                }
            }
            return _movableObject.transform.position;
        }
    
        private void TestObjectSelection()
        {
            Ray ray = _cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 200f, _objectsLayerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
            {
                if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject == _movableObject)
                {
                    Vector3 difference = hitInfo.point - _movableObject.transform.position;
                    _objectSelectionOffset = new Vector3(difference.x, 0f, difference.z);
                    _objectIsSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I not seeing?

Comment: So where should the object be? Your second paragraph is not clear to me.

Comment: @Everts It is meant to be following the path of the mouse. But when it is selected it will jump to center itself on the position of the mouse rather than move with the mouse with the initial offset rather than jumping to center itself. (Hope that makes sense)

Comment: I just tested your code as it is ... only using `if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` and it does exactly what you are asking for .... [gif](https://imgur.com/a/Q8rmGfP) .. except it stops if you move the mouse to fast but that's another question ;)

Comment: @derHugo just tried with that and still having the issue?

Comment: well it doesn't change how your code works ^^ I just used it in order to not have to deall with button settings .. I just wanted to state that basically I changed nothing in your code

Comment: @derHugo what happens in your example if the ground and the fustrum aren't parallel?

Comment: @Ruzihm lol honestly it is until now that I realize there are two different types of RayCasts ... should better sleep :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your difference is between the ray's collision with the surface of the building and the ground, and you're adding it to the ground to get the origin of the transform.

Instead, set the offset based on where the player's ray hits the ground:

```
    private void TestObjectSelection()
    {
        Ray ray = _cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 200f, _objectsLayerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
        {
            if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject == _movableObject)
            {
                Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
                float groundDistance;
                groundPlane.Raycast(ray, out groundDistance);

                Vector3 groundPoint = ray.GetPoint(groundDistance);

                // groundPoint is guaranteed y=0, so _objectSelectionOffset y=0;
                _objectSelectionOffset = _movableObject.transform.position - groundPoint;

                _objectIsSelected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

If your ground isn't a plane, you can use another `Physics.Raycast` to get the `groundPoint`:

```
    private void TestObjectSelection()
    {
        Ray ray = _cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 200f, _objectsLayerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
        {
            if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject == _movableObject)
            {
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 200f, _groundLayerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore)) 
                {
                    _objectSelectionOffset = _movableObject.transform.position - hitInfo.point;

                    _objectIsSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Either way, then you can set the position based on the offset:

```
    private Vector3 GetNewPosition()
    {
        if (_movableObject != null)
        {
            Ray ray = _cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 200f, _groundLayerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore))
            {
                return hitInfo.point + _objectSelectionOffset;
            }
        }
        return _movableObject.transform.position;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, It was where I was creating the offset using the hitpoint of the object not the ground, I knew it was something trivial i wasn't seeing, much appreciated.